# Combine AWS Lambda with Aurora Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, lumen

Is it possible to access Aurora Serverless DB from AWS Lambda?

In my case I have a Flutter mobile application which is communicating with Lumen micro framework through RESTful API. For DB I use MySQL.

After creating AWS Aurora cluster, can I connect to it like to a normal MySQL DB connection?

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=my.awshost.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I am relatively new to AWS. I've been only using EC2 so far. Therefore, I am trying to getting more familiar with Serverless concept.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can access like other service but there is limitation of Serverless DB, it can only accessible within VPC, so you should define Lambda in the same VPC and configure networking.

**Limitations of Aurora Serverless**

- Aurora with MySQL version 5.6 compatibility
- Aurora with PostgreSQL version 10.7 compatibility
- The port number for connections must be:

```
3306 for Aurora MySQL

5432 for Aurora PostgreSQL
```

- You can't give an **Aurora Serverless DB cluster a public IP address.** You can access an Aurora Serverless DB cluster **only from within a virtual private cloud (VPC)** based on the Amazon VPC service.
- Each Aurora Serverless DB cluster requires two AWS PrivateLink endpoints. If you reach the limit for PrivateLink endpoints within your VPC, you can't create any more Aurora Serverless clusters in that VPC. For information about checking and changing the limits on endpoints within a VPC, see Amazon VPC Limits.
- You can't access an Aurora Serverless DB cluster's endpoint through an AWS VPN connection or an inter-region VPC peering connection.

[aurora-serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html)

You can explore [getting-started-with-the-amazon-aurora-serverless-data-api](https://read.acloud.guru/getting-started-with-the-amazon-aurora-serverless-data-api-6b84e466b109) for configuration lambda with Serverless DB.